# Why can't my silly cardgame classes talk to each other?

Tags: c++

I have tried to make some sort of card game here but the classes for the holder / cardpile don't give away right things to the reciver/player and I don't know how to sort this out.

Here is the program:

```
 #include <iostream>

 using namespace std;

 class subclass // like a card
 {
 public:
    subclass();
    subclass(int x);
    int nummer;
    int getnummer();
 };

 subclass::subclass():nummer(0){}
 subclass::subclass(int x):nummer(x){}
 int subclass::getnummer()
 {
     return nummer;
 }
```

holder class:

```
 class holder // like a cardpile
 {
 public:
    holder();
    subclass cardpile[2];
    subclass* pile; // a cardpile which has 2 cards, with nummber 1 and 2.
    subclass* getsubclass(int i); // take first or second card.
 };
 holder::holder()
 {
    subclass first(1*3);
    subclass second(2*3);
    pile=cardpile;
    pile=&first;
    pile++;
    pile=&second;
    pile--;
 }

 subclass* holder::getsubclass(int i) //1 eller 2.
 {
     return pile+i;
 }
```

reciver class/ the player

```
 class reciver // like a player
 {
 public:
    subclass part_of_holder;
    reciver();
    void getsubclass( subclass* in); // give this card to player from this pointer
    void showinside(); // what card do player have
 };

 reciver::reciver():part_of_holder(){}

 void reciver::getsubclass( subclass* in)
 {
     part_of_holder=*in;
 }
 void reciver::showinside() // what card do player have
 {
     cout<< part_of_holder.getnummer();
 }
```

and the main

```
   int main()
    {
        holder cardpile;
        reciver player;

        cout << "first card should be 1*3 and it is : " ;
        player.getsubclass(cardpile.getsubclass(0));
        player.showinside();
        cout << endl <<"first card should be 2*3 and it is : " ;
        player.getsubclass(cardpile.getsubclass(1));
        player.showinside();

        return 0;
 }
```

In the end all I get is nonsence

Comment: tooo much codeeeeee...

Comment: The correct word is `receiver`.

Comment: tsk, next you will be telling him he spelt nummer wrong...

Comment: "in the end all i get is nonsence" actual output plz. Also, like @FaddishWorm said, it might help to post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: _"the holder / cardpile dont give away right things"_ - could you possibly be any more vague? You need to include relevant information such as what behavior you were expecting and what behavior you consider incorrect.

Comment: This question belongs to Code Review http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

```
holder::holder()
{
    subclass first(1*3);
    subclass second(2*3);
    pile=cardpile;
    pile=&first; // WRONG
    pile++;
    pile=&second;  // WRONG
    pile--;
}
```

The two lines above dont do what I suspect you think they do.
If you are trying to assign in the `cardpile` you would need something more like this:
`cardpile[0] = first` or `*pile = first`.

Sadly they wont work, since you dont have copy constructors. You also dont have any way to set a subclass's nummer field once constructed, so you are slightly doomed. 
Add a setter function to the get instruction, and you could write this:

```
cardpile[0].setnummer(first.getnummer());
```

Answer (score 3):

This is not going to work

```
holder::holder()
{
   subclass first(1*3);       // create temporary
   subclass second(2*3);      // create another temoporary
   pile=cardpile;             // assign member pointer to another member!!!
   pile=&first;               // assign member pointer to temporary   
   pile++;
   pile=&second;              // assign member pointer to temporary   
   pile--;
}

// member pointer pile points to object that no longer exists!!!
```

Basically once you create an instance of `holder` its internal `pile` pointer points to an object that no longer exists and that alone makes your class unstable because your `getsubclass` method returns an offset of this pointer - thus any attempt to dereference it will likely segfault.

In all honesty you would be better to start off again from scratch but a way of ensuring that you assign these temporaries to your member array would be

```
 cardpile[0] = subclass(1*3);
 cardpile[1] = subclass(2*3);
 pile = cardpile;
```

however, the way this code is written is not a good design and I would advise starting from scratch when your grasp of C++ is better.